# nginx - server_name - How the sequence matter

Tags: nginx

Here the question, i built nginx version 1.7.6 (i had the same with the 1.4.2) i need to manage the following domains :

- mydomain.company
- api.mydomain.company
- secure.mydomain.company
- www.mydomain.company

where only one of them is served by the http and all other redirect to https, here i post my nginx.conf file (i put all inside that for testing i know about the sites-available), but the problem is that when i add the api.mysite.company section that manage all the request WHY ??

```
 #user  nobody;
    worker_processes  1;

    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }

    http {
        include       mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;
        sendfile        on;
        #tcp_nopush     on;

        #keepalive_timeout  0;
        keepalive_timeout  65;

        #gzip  on;

    #################### api_backend ###############################

    upstream api_backend {

            server 127.0.0.1:3000;
            server 127.0.0.1:3001 backup;
        }

    ##################### api.mysite.company ############################

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name api.mysite.company;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://api_backend;
        }

    }

########################## mysite.company (80) #########################

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  mycompany.company secure.mycompany.company;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

###############################  HTTPS  #################################

    server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  mycompany.company secure.mycompany.company www.mycompany.company;

        ssl_certificate      /var/local/myc.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /var/local/myc.pem;

        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;
    ssl_protocols  SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

        location / {
            root   mycompany/secure;
            index  index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

if a move the ### mysite.company (80) #### section on top look like works good, but it seems  that sometime a conflict on the server_name raise !

Answer (score 0):

If there are more than one matches for [`server_name`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html), nginx will use the first one. Check the order that your configurations are evaluated in your sites-available directory.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

> When searching for a virtual server by name, if name matches more than
>   one of the specified variants, e.g. both wildcard name and regular
>   expression match, the first matching variant will be chosen, in the
>   following order of precedence:
>
> - exact name
> - longest wildcard name starting with an asterisk, e.g. “`*.example.org`”
> - longest wildcard name ending with an asterisk, e.g. “`mail.*`”
> - first matching regular expression (in order of appearance in a configuration file)

I believe this part of nginx's documentation is "nothing more nothing less" regarding the question.